# Complicated CGT conundrum

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

My husband and I bought a house with two other people 12 years ago. We were going to go into business with them, but shortly after we fell out with one of them making the whole situation very difficult. Now they want to sell, which we are fine with, but we have had nothing to do with the property for the whole 12 years. We are set to gain nothing from the sale either. We are not bothered about trying to force them to share the equity as we just want to be untangled from them. But, how are we going to declare on the CGT form that we have made no gains from it? It's such a strange scenario that I can't seem to get a clear answer from anyone. Please can someone help?

Comment: are you getting any money from the sale? did you claim and income or expenses regarding the property?

Comment: We are getting nothing from the sale. We have had no income or claimed any expenses for the property. We simply helped them to get the mortgage. Originally, we had agreed to share the proceeds at the point of sale. But, after a bitter falling out we have been unable to extracate ourselved from the mortgage until they were ready to sell. I'm at a loss as to what to do as I know we should technically declare the sale of an asett

Comment: @WMorgan do you have any contract showing your terms of ownership and sale? Will you?

Comment: You probably don't need to put in the actual figures involved, but I think you need to clarify how/where money changed hands. Does "_We simply helped them to get the mortgage_" mean you gave them a downpayment, helped pay the monthly payment etc.? Does "_We are getting nothing from the sale_" mean you won't get _any_ money from the sale of the property, or that you won't _make_ any money from the sale?

Comment: We helped by putting our names on the mortgage. They had a lot of properties already and were struggling to get any more credit. Our good credit effectively gave them the leverage to take out another mortgage. We won't get any money at all from the sale. I'm sure that we could argue that we should, but we don't want the hassle.

Comment: I am struggling to understand. How much *money* did you pay towards the house? How much *money* are you going to get when the house is sold? If these amounts are "£X,000" and "£0", then why are you worried about capital *gains* tax?.

Comment: I'm not worried about having to pay CGT, I just don't know if I need to fill in the HMRC tool and if I do how do I fill it in to make sure they know we didn't make anything from it. There isn't a box to explain the scenario.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who helped. I have a way forward now.

Answer (score 5):

> We helped by putting our names on the mortgage.

You signed the mortgage as a guarantor.

> Originally, we had agreed to share the proceeds at the point of sale.

You gained an equity interest through a verbal agreement with the borrower, but the bank was not informed (how unsporting of you, not to get the bank's permission). The bank still thinks you are just a guarantor with no equity interest.

> We won't get any money at all from the sale. I'm sure that we could
> argue that we should, but we don't want the hassle.

If you want minimum hassle, you could forget that your equity interest, via verbal agreement, ever existed. When the mortgage is paid off, your guarantor status will end.

There is nothing to declare to the tax authorities when one is relieved of one's responsibilities as a guarantor. If you like, you could ask the bank to write to confirm to you that you are no longer a guarantor for the mortgage, i.e. that the mortgage has been paid off.